# Registery install programs containing space

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Win32;
namespace Demo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetInstallApps();


        }
        public void GetInstallApps()
        {
            string uninstallkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            RegistryKey rk;
            using (rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallkey))
            {
                foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            lsitBox1.Items.Add(sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + "   " + sk.GetValue("DisplayVersion"));
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        { }
                    }
                }
              //  txtblock1.Text = lsitBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Application give information about All install software in my windows but it containing space, i want to delete that space , And i know it will register with registery key, Because of that it will containing space if i want to remove that particular registry what can i do any idea Thank you

Comment: string.Trim() ?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hey Tell me whats the problem in it . You down voted it's good . but at least give a reason for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before try catch block add one line

if (sk.GetValue("") != null)

Comment: It's not null It's containing value and its give a space when i debug it it will show me some key's I search many things on it and i know it's containing registry key without display name

Comment: @Dhru'soni did you tried the same line that i suggest you